# Recharts render pie chart vertically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I am using [recharts](http://recharts.org/en-US/api/Pie) library for pie charts.

I want to load pie chart for two values always.The chart is loading horizantally as you can see [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rechart-pie-chart-w-custom-label-example-37xk1) starting from angle 0.
But i want it to be starting from angle 90 looking as below.

[image]

PS: Tried changing startAngle and endAngle values.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well I guess it's still related with props `startAngle` and `endAngle`

It starts counting at degree **90**. (It may be kind of counterintuitive)

If you try another value as below, it would become a ***vertical start*** pie

```
startAngle={-270}
```

Notice according to the document, the default value:

- startAngle: 0
- endAngle: 360

---

The diff equals 360 would show a full circle pie. You can try out other pairs, like

```
[-270, 90], [90, -270], [45, 405]
```

[image]